# delete string in file php

Tags: php, file

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fn="file.php";
$str=file_get_contents($fn);

if (empty($str)){
die('Failed to fetch data');
}else{
$oldMessage = "Hello";
$deletedFormat = "bye";
$str = str_replace($oldMessage, $deletedFormat,$str,$count);

if(file_put_contents($fn, $str)){
   echo 'Total replace: '.$count;
}
}

}
```

I am trying to delete a string in the file that I am opening up. However, it is not working.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your file. Fix all the errors. Also, read the documentation for [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) (hint: you should not be using `fopen()` for anything).

Comment: `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` are wrappers for `fopen` and `fclose`. You shouldn't combine them. Just use `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 4):

`file_get_contents` expects the first parameter to be a filename not a file resource.

http://php.net/file_get_contents

So the calls to `fopen` and `fclose` are not necessary, instead call it like so

```
$str = file_get_contents($fn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget about checking the function results. Here's a simple example script:

```
$fn="file.php";
$str=file_get_contents($fn);

if (empty($str)){
    die('Failed to fetch data');
}else{
    $oldMessage = "Hello";
    $deletedFormat = "";
    $str = str_replace($oldMessage, $deletedFormat,$str,$count);

    if(file_put_contents($fn, $str)){
       echo 'Total replace: '.$count;
    }
}
```